# How to drop a unique index that is used upon a foreighn key?

Tags: mariadb

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `activation_token` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token_expiration` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` enum('EMPLOYEE','MANAGER') NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `last_update_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `vaccations` (
  `vaccation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `from` date NOT NULL,
  `until` date NOT NULL,
  `approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `comments` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`vaccation_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `vaccations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `date_range_valid` CHECK (`from` <= `until`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And I created the following index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS no_duplicate_vaccations ON vaccations(`user_id`,`from`,aproval_status);
```

But once I try to drop it:

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS no_duplicate_vaccations on vaccations;
```

How I can drop it in a manner that I will not lode data due to cascading?

Comment: Did you get an error message from the DROP?  What do you mean by "lode data"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to drop and re-create the fopreign key index:

```
ALTER TABLE vaccations DROP FOREIGN KEY IF EXISTS vaccations_ibfk_1 ;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS no_duplicate_vaccations on vaccations;
ALTER TABLE vaccations ADD CONTRAINT vaccations_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users(user_id) ;
```

In order to ensure that theese commands will run in one-go run it upon a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE vaccations DROP FOREIGN KEY IF EXISTS vaccations_ibfk_1 ;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS no_duplicate_vaccations on vaccations;
ALTER TABLE vaccations ADD CONTRAINT vaccations_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users(user_id) ;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Older versions of MySQL do not honor BEGIN+COMMIT for wrapping DDL statements.  Instead, combine the 3 ALTERs into a single ALTER statement.